# php format html output in a single line

Tags: php, wordpress, format

So i have the next scenario using [supersized slideshow](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html) in wordpress. on title i want to output html code, from wordpress posts. The code looks like this:

```
$output .= '{image : "'.$img_url.'", title : "'.do_shortcode($content).'", thumb : "'.$thumbnailsrc.'", url : ""},'."\n";
```

writing a post content in a single line, like this:

```
<h1>hei there</h1><span>how are you?</span>
```

it will output:

```
{image : "http://localhost/mef/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/nature_0014.jpg", title : "<h1>hei there</h1><span>how are you?</span>", thumb : "http://localhost/mef/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/nature_0014-90x45.jpg", url : ""}
```

what is ok and working. But wordpress once u switch to Visual, adds indent to your code and it will look like this:

```
<h1>Hei there</h1>
<span>how are you?</span>
```

and the output in this case will brake the slideshow:

```
{image : "http://localhost/mef/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/nature_0014.jpg", title : "<h1>hei there</h1>
<span>how are you?</span>", thumb : "http://localhost/mef/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/nature_0014-90x45.jpg", url : ""}
```

is there anyway i could tell php not to break the line there and output all the `do_shortcode($content)` in a single line

Comment: You're hand-generating JSON.  Don't do that.  Use `json_encode()`: http://php.net/json-encode

Comment: Yes, using json_encode() solved the problem, perfectly.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$noLineBreak = str_replace(array("\n", "\r\n", PHP_EOL), "", $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable wpautop() `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');`